# mysql: check if interval between two dates is less than 1 second

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

Ok, I need something like this:

```
datediff(second, date_one, date_two) < 1
```

dates are stored in a column 'datetime' type

**UPDATE**

I want to find dates which differ in less than several (say, 10) seconds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second is the smallest unit in DATETIME fields. If you want to check that the difference is less than 1 second, that means that the two dates must be the same, in which case you can simply use the equivalency operator.

To check the time difference using bigger units you can use TIMEDIFF with TIME_TO_SEC. For example to check if two datetimes are between 10 seconds of each other

```
ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(datetime1, datetime2))) < 10
```

Comment: ok, I stated my goal not correctly, let difference be, say, 10 *seconds*

Answer (score 1):

`ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, datetime1, datetime2)) < 10`

This allows for easily changing the units and it is now possible to do such comparisons using MICROSECOND as well.

Comment: how do I use this as an if statement, like if less than 1 hour difference between these two datetimes then select the record else do not, as i get the context of the answer but how do i use it in an sql statement?